# How to calculate previous days from selected end date

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In my data model I have calender table.I Want get quantity for 2 days previous date.I use below measure.But the issue is  (Sheet1)'[qty]) table doesnt have records for sundays.If user select Tuesday  from the calender slicer It will return sunday date.I want get the data for saturday.If there is no any record for the date getting TwoDaysPreviousDay variable it should return last 2nd date records availble.If there is a holiday in the weekdays I want do the same.According to my data model I cant use date from  (Sheet1)'[date] as the slicer date.

```
2Days Previous =    VAR TwoDaysPreviousDay = LASTDATE(Mycalender[Date])-2
                    VAR TwoDaysPreviousDayQty = CALCULATE(
                                                SUM('Table 1 (Sheet1)'[qty]),
                                                    Mycalender[Date]=TwoDaysPreviousDay
                                                         )
                Return TwoDaysPreviousDayQty
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
2Days Previous  = 
  var fromDate = LASTDATE(Mycalender[Date])
  var prev2 = TOPN(2,
    FILTER(ALL('Table 1 (Sheet1)'), 'Table 1 (Sheet1)'[Date] < fromDate), 
    [Date], DESC
   )
  var bottom1 = TOPN(1, prev2, [Date], ASC)
  return IF(
    COUNTROWS(prev2) > 1,
    CALCULATE(MIN('Table 1 (Sheet1)'[qty]), bottom1)
  )
```

Comment: How to use same technique for 3rd last day 04th last date @Sam Nseir

Comment: Change `TOPN(2` to the number you want